# How to secure REST web service with Spring, DELETE is possible although I don't authorzed it

Tags: spring, spring-security

I'm setting up a security config in Spring and I want that only the user can access to the resources that I wrote in the config. If I don't wrote `DELETE` I don't want any user can use this request for example, 
that is the most restrictive unless I add it. What should I change on my code?

I wrote the next code. `GET` and `POST` is ok, but I can delete and I don't add  this authorization.

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityJavaConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .inMemoryAuthentication()                             
                .withUser("user")
                    .password(encoder().encode("passExample"))
                    .roles("USER");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
            .httpBasic()
                .and()
            .csrf()
                .disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/**").hasRole("USER")
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/**").hasRole("USER")
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .permitAll();

....
```

I expected that If I make a request with `DELETE`, the application does not allow because I have not authorized it.

```
curl -X Delete locahost/servicio/1
```

```
{
    "timestamp": "2019-05-09T17:43:30.253+0000",
    "status": 401,
    "error": "Unauthorized",
    "message": "Unauthorized",
    "path": "/service"
}
```

But the actual output is status 204. The server successfully processed the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to restrict any other request, see [Spring Security Reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.1.5.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#jc-authorize-requests):

> **6.4 Authorize Requests**
>
> Our examples have only required users to be authenticated and have done so for every URL in our application. We can specify custom requirements for our URLs by adding multiple children to our http.authorizeRequests() method. For example:
>
> ```java
> protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
>     http
>         .authorizeRequests()                                                                1
>             .antMatchers("/resources/**", "/signup", "/about").permitAll()                  2
>             .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")                                      3
>             .antMatchers("/db/**").access("hasRole('ADMIN') and hasRole('DBA')")            4
>             .anyRequest().authenticated()                                                   5
>             .and()
>         // ...
>         .formLogin();
> }
> ```
>
> 1. There are multiple children to the `http.authorizeRequests()` method each matcher is considered in the order they were declared.
> 2. We specified multiple URL patterns that any user can access. Specifically, any user can access a request if the URL starts with "/resources/", equals "/signup", or equals "/about".
> 3. Any URL that starts with "/admin/" will be restricted to users who have the role "ROLE_ADMIN". You will notice that since we are invoking the hasRole method we do not need to specify the "ROLE_" prefix.
> 4. Any URL that starts with "/db/" requires the user to have both "ROLE_ADMIN" and "ROLE_DBA". You will notice that since we are using the hasRole expression we do not need to specify the "ROLE_" prefix.
> 5. Any URL that has not already been matched on only requires that the user be authenticated

and see [`ExpressionUrlAuthorizationConfigurer#denyAll`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.1.5.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configurers/ExpressionUrlAuthorizationConfigurer.AuthorizedUrl.html#denyAll--):

> **denyAll**
>
> ```
> public ExpressionUrlAuthorizationConfigurer.ExpressionInterceptUrlRegistry denyAll()
> ```
>
> Specify that URLs are not allowed by anyone.

Your modified code:

```java
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http
        .httpBasic()
            .and()
        .csrf()
            .disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/**").hasRole("USER")
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/**").hasRole("USER")
            .anyRequest().denyAll()
            .and()
        .formLogin()
            .permitAll();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you've configured is any `GET` and `POST` request to any endpoints should have user role `ROLE_USER` and premit all other types of requests like (`DELETE`, `HEAD`, `PUT`, etc.). Try denying all other types of requests.

`.antMatchers("/**").denyAll();`  or
  `.anyRequest().denyAll();`

Please note that order matters here. If you specify this before `GET` or `POST` request then all requests would be denied.